# elasticsearch - can mix number and number array datatype in same index same type?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I created 2 documents of autogenerated test data in an index/type using:

```
POST /mymixedata/lists-and-nums/
{
  "pat_first_name": "Balduin",
  "pat_last_name": "Goodbairn",
  "gender": "Male",
  "diag_codes": "T84028D",
  "prov_first_name": "Dwight",
  "prov_last_name": "Croutear",
  "prov_addr": "617 Monterey Drive",
  "rand_list": [
    123,
    456,
    123
  ],
  "notes": "Quisque porta volutpat erat. Quisque erat eros, viverra eget, congue eget, semper rutrum, nulla. Nunc purus."
}


POST mymixedata/lists-and-nums
{
  "pat_first_name": "Goorbi",
  "pat_last_name": "Goorbson",
  "gender": "Female",
  "diag_codes": "S22039D",
  "prov_first_name": "Tarrah",
  "prov_last_name": "Jimeno",
  "prov_addr": "13483 Walton Road",
  "rand_list": 100,
  "notes": "Phasellus sit amet erat. Nulla tempus. Vivamus in felis eu sapien cursus vestibulum.\n\nProin eu mi. Nulla ac enim. In tempor, turpis nec euismod scelerisque, quam turpis adipiscing lorem, vitae mattis nibh ligula nec sem.\n\nDuis aliquam convallis nunc. Proin at turpis a pede posuere nonummy. Integer non velit.\n\nDonec diam neque, vestibulum eget, vulputate ut, ultrices vel, augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec pharetra, magna vestibulum aliquet ultrices, erat tortor sollicitudin mi, sit amet lobortis sapien sapien non mi. Integer ac neque.\n\nDuis bibendum. Morbi non quam nec dui luctus rutrum. Nulla tellus.\n\nIn sagittis dui vel nisl. Duis ac nibh. Fusce lacus purus, aliquet at, feugiat non, pretium quis, lectus."
}
```

Notice that for the field `rand_list`, one doc has an array of nums and the other has a single num. Querying the index/type like so:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "rand_list": {
              "gt": "50"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I get back both of the documents, which seems like the behavior that I want (assuming its checking the array of nums in the fist doc and the single num in the second to determine if they contain a value > 50).

Other than [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html), I can't find much documentation on how elastic treats fields that sometimes have arrays and sometimes have single values.

Can anyone explain what's going on? Do single values count as arrays even when they don't have surrounding brackets (ie. is `field: 123` same as `field: [123]` in a doc)?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I just did not read the docs close enough. Turns out that [yes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html#CO177-3), can have either arrays or single values of same datatype for the same fields in documents.